# Add multiple files to a category in Wikimedia Commons

Tags: wikipedia, mediawiki, wikimedia-commons

There are some instances where I'd like to add multiple articles to a category on a MediaWiki site such as Wikimedia Commons (for example, adding multiple images of airplanes to the category "Airplanes.") Is it possible to add multiple articles to a single category without manually editing each page and copying and pasting the category into the page's source?

(By any chance, does AutoWikiBot or a similar tool help to automate this process?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you have a list of pages that you want to add to some category, [AutoWikiBrowser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aAutoWikiBrowser) can help you do that. But, as with any other mass change, you should have a consensus to do so, or the change should be uncontroversial.

Also, to be able to use AWB on Commons, you need to be approved first, see [Commons:AutoWikiBrowser](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Commons%3aAutoWikiBrowser) for more information.

Comment: What steps should I take, specifically, in order to do this in AutoWikiBrowser (as soon as I've installed it)?

Comment: Have a look at [the User Manual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:AutoWikiBrowser/User_manual#More...).